# Reasonable length of trace?

Tags: sql-server-profiler

What's the overhead like for running a long SQL Server Profiler trace? Any considerations to running a 24 hour trace on production server? I'd like to get a good sample of what's going on when actual users are using the system instead of running mock-up sessions that try to mimic full spectrum of user activity.

Comment: I think the sql profiler is not a appropiate tool for a session for more than 24 hours. The main goal to use it is for debugging

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would you see is a reasonable length? 5 hours? 30 minutes?

Comment: I'm not an expert for this. I think not longer than sixty minutes.